# DST_OFFSET changes when it should not

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I am trying to run below code. I define a timezone with dst starting from 4th Sunday March 2 am and end it on 5th Sunday March 2 am.

```
  SimpleTimeZone st = new SimpleTimeZone(-18000000, "DSTTesting", Calendar.MARCH, 4, 1, 7200000, Calendar.MARCH, -1, 1, 7200000);

  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(st);
  cal.set(2013, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
  System.out.println("DST_OFFSET before subtracting hours : "+cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET));
  cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -2);
  System.out.println("DST_OFFSET after subtracting hours : "+cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET));
```

The output is:
DST_OFFSET before subtracting hours : 0
DST_OFFSET after subtracting hours : 3600000

Not sure why the DST_OFFSET changes when I subtract 2 hours from Jan 2013 1 am. Ideally Jan 1 2013 and Dec 31 2012, both the dates are out of the DST period of the TimeZone I created so both should have same value for DST_OFFSET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some invalid constructor arguments.  Refer to the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SimpleTimeZone.html).

You are specifying start values of:

```
Calendar.MARCH, 4, 1
```

If you meant "March 4th", then you should have specified a zero for the day of week value:

```
Calendar.MARCH, 4, 0
```

If you meant "The first Sunday on or after March 4th", then you should have specified a negative day of week value:

```
Calendar.MARCH, 4, -1
```

The end date you specified looks ok.  It was:

```
Calendar.MARCH, -1, 1
```

That means "The last Sunday in March".

I'm not sure why exactly the DST would be off because of this, but try correcting it and see if it makes a difference.

Also - you should seriously consider the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library instead of this.  You will have much more reliable results, and you won't have to implement all of the DST rules yourself.

**UPDATE**

Reading [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DST_OFFSET) carefully, it's not clear that `cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)` takes into effect the current date of the calendar, or if it just returns the daylight offset associated with the time zone.  It's worded as:

> This field reflects the correct daylight saving offset value of the
>   time zone of this Calendar if the TimeZone implementation subclass
>   supports historical Daylight Saving Time schedule changes

Perhaps you should try this instead?

```
boolean dst = st.inDaylightTime(cal.getTime());
```

I am just guessing here.  I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: fourth Sunday of March should be written as 
 Calendar.MARCH, 21, -1
But still after doing this change, the output is same. DST_OFFSET changes from 0 to 3600000 on subtracting hours.

Comment: Please let me know if the code I posted in the updated answer works for you.  Thanks.

Comment: tried boolean dst = st.inDaylightTime(cal.getTime());
dst evaluates to false before subtracting hours and to true after subtracting.
I think this is related to year change to 2012, as long as I remain in  the year 2013 by subtracting hours, DST_OFFSET behaves as expected.

Comment: If you set the start year to a lower value, does it work then?  See [SimpleTimeZone.setStartYear(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SimpleTimeZone.html#setStartYear(int))

Comment: If I change start year to cal.set(2012, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0); it keeps the DST value same. That means my dst duration for the timezone I created works for current year only.output is:
DST_OFFSET before subtracting hours : 3600000
DST_OFFSET after subtracting hours : 3600000

Comment: I think normally that year would be set to the first year that the DST rule went into law.  So that makes sense

Comment: If I use below constructor with time mode UTC or Standard time it works fine.
SimpleTimeZone(int rawOffset, String ID, int startMonth, int startDay, int startDayOfWeek, int startTime, int startTimeMode, int endMonth, int endDay, int endDayOfWeek, int endTime, int endTimeMode, int dstSavings)